# Search with Arabic Numbers within a text in SQL Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, collation

I have a string column of type NVARCHAR in my table that stores Arabic text contains Arabic letters such as: جهاز ٦٠ للخدمة

The problem is that I cannot retrieve this piece of data when I search for it

```
declare @textdesc as nvarchar(70) = 'جهاز ٦٠ للخدمة'
Select *
from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 
              on t1.prmkey = t2.frgnkey
where t1.text LIKE '%'+@textdesc+'%'
```

But when I search by any other field other than @textdesc, it converts the Arabic numbers into English numbers to be

```
جهاز 60 للخدمة
```

in the search results. I don't get the text that is stored in the database with the Arabic numbers. I don't know why this happens. Can you help me figure this out?

I tried to search by

```
where @textdesc LIKE N'%' +@textdesc + '%'
```

and it doesn't work either.

My database collation is Arabic_CI_AS

Comment: Your literal string is a `varchar` not an `nvarchar`, so your variable will have a value like `'??????'`.

Comment: For starters, try `declare @textdesc as nvarchar(70) = N'جهاز ٦٠ للخدمة';`

Comment: @DanGuzman Thank you a lot, it works. 
but why does it work when N in the declaration and doesn't work when it is in the where statement ?

Comment: You need to use [`N`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025032/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-prefix-n-in-t-sql-statements) prefix otherwise SQL Server will treat your string as a varchar.

Comment: Because of what I mentioned in my comment, @MNada. `'{unicode character}' = '?'`. You **need** to declare your literal string as an `nvarchar` (by prefixing it with an `N`). The `'%'` would be implicitly cast to an `nvarchar` use to data type precedence, as `varchar` has a lower precedence.

Comment: @MNada, without the `N` prefix to denote a Unicode literal, the literal is interpreted as a non-Unicode string. Characters outside the ASCII range are interpretted according to the current database default collation code page and characters with no mapping are either converted to `?` or a fallback character.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LIKE operator, N and % SQL Server doesn't work on nvarchar column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54106222/like-operator-n-and-sql-server-doesnt-work-on-nvarchar-column)

Answer (score 1):

As a lot of the comments suggest. The trick here is to use the prefix N''. 
I found a question asking about the N'' prefix where you can read about ["What is the meaning of the prefix N in T-SQL statements?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025032/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-prefix-n-in-t-sql-statements), which should solve your problem.